# Шифрование ECDSA с кривой brainpoolP160r1

Tags: c#, шифрование

Никак не могу реализовать или найти реализованный алгоритм шифрования **ECDSA** с параметрами кривой **brainpoolP160r1**.

Пробовал библиотеку *BouncyCastle*, но в ней нет этой кривой. Задать параметры вручную нельзя, да и буквами параметры у них обозначаются другими.

Пробовал встроенными библиотеками  `System.Security.Cryptography` использовав класс `ECDsaCng`, но в нём я вообще не нашёл где указываются параметры кривой.

Уже не знаю где искать и читать...

Может кто реализовывал этот алгоритм, направьте меня, пожалуйста, в нужное русло.

---

Решил, как и посоветовали в комментарии, задать параметры самому. [По этому документу](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5639) даны значения: A, B, x, y, p, q, h. А в структуре [ECParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecparameters(v=vs.110).aspx), что нужна для создания своей кривой фигурируют буквы D, Q и в самой кривой ещё x и y. В D и Q тоже есть свои x, y. Я что-то вообще запутался, куда какие значения подставляются?

Comment: Используйте метод `ImportParameters` у класса `ECDsaCng` - там можно указать параметры кривой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Framework'e 4.7 есть эта кривая, но на данный момент ее не реализовали в SecureChannel. Возможно этот способ будет работать в будущем, а пока что `PlatformNotSupportedException`:

```
ECDsaCng ecdsa = new ECDsaCng(ECCurve.NamedCurves.brainpoolP160r1);
```

---

Можно попробовать задать кривую вручную, но это так же не работает на данный момент (тот же `PlatformNotSupportedException`):

```
ECCurve curve = new ECCurve();
curve.A = BitHelper.HexToBytes("340E7BE2A280EB74E2BE61BADA745D97E8F7C300");
curve.B = BitHelper.HexToBytes("1E589A8595423412134FAA2DBDEC95C8D8675E58");
curve.Prime = BitHelper.HexToBytes("E95E4A5F737059DC60DFC7AD95B3D8139515620F");
curve.Order = BitHelper.HexToBytes("E95E4A5F737059DC60DF5991D45029409E60FC09");
curve.G = new ECPoint
{
    X = BitHelper.HexToBytes("BED5AF16EA3F6A4F62938C4631EB5AF7BDBCDBC3"),
    Y = BitHelper.HexToBytes("1667CB477A1A8EC338F94741669C976316DA6321")
};
curve.Cofactor = new byte[] { 1 };
curve.CurveType = ECCurve.ECCurveType.PrimeShortWeierstrass;

ECDsaCng ecdsa = new ECDsaCng(curve);
```

---

Используя BouncyCastle:

```
var curve = new FpCurve(
    new BigInteger("E95E4A5F737059DC60DFC7AD95B3D8139515620F", 16),
    new BigInteger("340E7BE2A280EB74E2BE61BADA745D97E8F7C300", 16),
    new BigInteger("1E589A8595423412134FAA2DBDEC95C8D8675E58", 16),
    new BigInteger("E95E4A5F737059DC60DF5991D45029409E60FC09", 16),
    BigInteger.One);

var g = curve.CreatePoint(
    new BigInteger("BED5AF16EA3F6A4F62938C4631EB5AF7BDBCDBC3", 16),
    new BigInteger("1667CB477A1A8EC338F94741669C976316DA6321", 16));

var random = new SecureRandom();

var generator = new ECKeyPairGenerator();
generator.Init(new ECKeyGenerationParameters(new ECDomainParameters(curve, g, curve.Order), random));
var keyPair = generator.GenerateKeyPair();

byte[] message = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withECDSA");
signer.Init(true, new ParametersWithRandom(keyPair.Private, random));
signer.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature();

signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withECDSA");
signer.Init(false, keyPair.Public);
signer.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
bool ok = signer.VerifySignature(signature);
```

Comment: Исключение: "Указанная кривая "brainpoolP160r1" или ее параметры недопустимы для этой платформы." Получается битность ОС не подходит? Поэтому и решил вручную забить данные.

Comment: Проблема не в битности, эти классы используют нативную библиотеку Windows - SecureChannel. Видимо там не реализовали ее.

Comment: это какая-то виндовая библиотека чтоль? Как мне всё таки вызвать эту кривую, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Николай я боюсь что эти .NET-классы  не могут работать с кастомными кривыми (по крайней мере в меня никак не получается подставить вашу кривую). Могу вам предложить свою библиотеку для ECDSA

Comment: буду рад любой помощи

Comment: @Николай добавил как при помощи BouncyCastle сделать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77189/discussion-between--and-zergatul).